# Calculate range a number fall into

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get an idea of which range a number falls into. What I mean is, lets say the scale is 900 and we slice it into 4 areas.

```
function getLocationRange(input){
  const slices = 4;
  const scale = 900;

  const slice = scale / slices;


  if(input < slice){
    return 0;
  } else if (input < slice * 2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (input < slice * 3) {
    return 2;
  } else if (input < slice * 4) {
    return 3;
  }
}

getLocationRange(50); // 0
getLocationRange(800); // 3
getLocationRange(400); // 1
```

Basically if the input number falls into the first quarter it returns 0, the second quarter returns 1, etc...

The trouble is, this doesn't scale because I need else statements for every slice (say I wanted to run it with 6 slices or 100 slices instead).

Is there a simple math equation to achieve the same effect? (Don't worry about negative or greater than or equal to scale.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getRange(input, scale, slices) {
    return Math.floor(input / (scale / slices));
}
```

Comment: A little explanation about how to derive this answer from your code: in your conditions divide both sides by `slice`. Using `const x = input / slice;` you now have: `if (x < 1) { return 0; } else if (x < 2) { return 1) else if (x < 3) { return 2; } ...` etc. In each case `x` is turned into (the return value) the nearest integer below or equal to `x`. This is exactly what `Math.floor(x)` does.